# How to RateLimit forgot-password requests in Laravel Fortify?

Tags: php, laravel, fortify

I am using Fortify (Laravel 8), and it does provide RateLimiter for `login` and `two-factor`, but not for the `forgot-password` requests.

Without a (IP Address) RateLimiter, a very simple bot can execute a huge amount of outgoing emails, basically getting the email service suspended or causing huge costs when using SMTP services that charge per number of emails sent.

I have already tried:

```
RateLimiter::for('forgot-password', function (Request $request) {
   return Limit::perMinute(1)->by($request->ip());
});
```

In my `FortifyServiceProvider.php`, but it doesn't work!

There is also no routes in the `routes/web.php` file to manually apply the throttle middleware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked at this aswell, and the backend actually throttles too many requests **for a specific email**. However, that is done through `422 Unprocessable Entity` (which is usually a validation error), like so:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["Please wait before retrying."]}}
```

I've came across your question because I was looking to throttle `/fortify/reset-password` and `/fortify/forgot-password` (password.update/password.email) based on the **IP only**. Both required the user's email address and thus enables an attacker to test existing email addresses, as the backend will happily tell you if it exists or not—without rate limit! The existing rate limit mentioned above (`422`) will only kick in for multiple requests for one specific email. So this won't help if someone were to enumerate possible emails.

My solution is for `reset-password` and `forgot-password` (and rather a workaround). I will omit the `reset-password` as it is equal to `forgot-password`.

However, this requires you to overwrite fortify's published route in your `web.php`. No changes are made to any vendor files. You will have to ensure that after upgrading fortify that the route registration is still equal to the original (https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/master/routes/routes.php)

1. Let's add a new rate limiter [`app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php`]

This will allow 10 requests per minute per IP

```
public function boot()
    {
        // ...
        RateLimiter::for('forgot-password', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(10)->by($request->ip());
        });
    }
```

2. Add it to your fortify config [`config/fortify.php`]

```
 'limiters' => [
        // ...
        'forgot-password' => 'forgot-password',
    ],
```

3. Make sure that your fortify service provider is called **before** your own route service provider (which is the case when installed via official Laravel docs) [`config/app.php`]

```
'providers' => [

        // ...
        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,


        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */

        // ...
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

4. You can now overwrite the route and attach the rate limiter [`routes/web.php`]

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\PasswordResetLinkController;

//...

$limiter = config('fortify.limiters.forgot-password');
// Copied from
// https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/c64f1e8263417179d06fd986ef8d716d4c5689e2/routes/routes.php#L55
// with addition of the throttle middleware.
// TODO: Keep this updated when updating fortify!
Route::post(config('fortify.prefix', 'fortify') . '/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware(['guest', 'throttle:' . $limiter])
    ->name('password.email');
```

More than 10 requests from one IP will now throw a `429 Too Many Requests` from you backend to the client.

The nice thing about this is that you only overwrite the route-registration but can still use all fortify features as it uses the stock controller.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to use Breeze instead as I have full controll over everything with it. But I still wonder why does laravel's RateLimit key, for login, and all other auth pages is "{$ip}|{$email}" (basically a combination of IP Address and Email), it could easily be only for IP address, and more secure that way, as a single IP can't be used for countless login emails before using another IP by the attacker.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I think what the laravel implementation is aiming at is to prevent brute-force attacks against a specific email address. In the meantime I've also replaced fortify, but with own controllers and based those on the breeze code. This then allows to prevent the attack you've mentioned by appending throttle when registering the route.

Comment: @J.Doe there can be even tenths of thousands of users using the same IP address, so, generally limiting users based on just the IP address can be problematic. At the other hand, just for this particular route, we can use a rate limiter based on IP address, as it will be less likely many users will need to reset their passwords and having the same IP, meaning we're going to **apply the limiter just to that specific route**. We can add another layer of uniqueness like users browser agent string, but that can be even randomized quite easily by the attacker's script.

Comment: Hi, when I add the code in route.php and go to forgot-password page, this redirect when click in button forgot password. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me.

You can change fortify's `auth.php` file like this:

```php
'passwords' => [
  'users' => [
    'provider' => 'users',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
    'throttle' => 60,
  ],
  'fortify' => [
    'provider' => 'users',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
    'throttle' => 10,
  ],
],
```

And then in `app\config\fortify.php` change:

`'passwords' => 'users'` to `'passwords' => 'fortify'`